# How to use endpoint for dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I don't need to set up the DAX cluster which already provides an endpoint to connect to. I only need to connect to this dynamodb table from an internal service. But the table doesn't expose a URL to connect to. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use **AWS SDK's dynamodb interface**, e.g. [client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html) in boto3. All the endpoints for the dynamodb are already provided by default in the SDKs, so you don't have to explicitly specify it.

The endpoints for dynamodb are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ddb.html).

Comment: I cannot use an external client. As I don't have access to the code of the service which needs to connect. I need to supply DYNAMODB_URL as an env variable.

Comment: @Viren I udpated the answer.

Comment: I see. thanks for answering such a basic question.

Comment: @Marcin I actually want to use the endpoint, just to try it out once. The page you have linked to provides only a generic endpoint for the entire region. Then what? I tried adding more info, like `/<table-name>` or `/tables/<table>`, but all I get is 404's

Comment: @mblakesley Please make dedicated question for your issue.